# Output of SQL to be written on Excel In Standard path

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to save the output of a SQL query to Excel and save in the standard path. I used `OPENROWSET` to write the output.

But I'm getting this error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'Philips'.

Please share your valuable suggestions.

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
                       'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\testing.xls;', 
       'DECLARE @VPTVARCHAR(24) SET @VPT= 'Philips'
        DECLARE @DAYS INT SET @DAYS = -30   

        SELECT * 
        INTO #XTP1 
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT 'START' AS DTT, DATEADD(D,@DAYS,DATEACTIONED) AS DT 
              FROM REPORTS
              WHERE VPT = @VPT          
              UNION             
              SELECT DISTINCT 'CHANGE' AS DTT, DATEACTIONED AS DT  
              FROM REPORTS
              WHERE VPT = @VPT          
              UNION             
              SELECT 'END' AS DTT, DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())) AS DT) AS A
              FROM [Sheet1$]'
```

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at `'Philips'`. You have faulty quotes and also missing the closing bracket.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add double quotes:

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
                       'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\testing.xls;', 
       'DECLARE @VPTVARCHAR(24) SET @VPT= ''Philips''
        DECLARE @DAYS INT SET @DAYS = -30   

        SELECT * 
        INTO #XTP1 
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ''START'' AS DTT, DATEADD(D,@DAYS,DATEACTIONED) AS DT 
              FROM REPORTS
              WHERE VPT = @VPT          
              UNION             
              SELECT DISTINCT ''CHANGE'' AS DTT, DATEACTIONED AS DT  
              FROM REPORTS
              WHERE VPT = @VPT          
              UNION             
              SELECT ''END'' AS DTT, DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())) AS DT) AS A
              FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

That will get rid of the syntax error, not looks at the query though